# Python Pandas error

Tags: python, pandas

First of all, hello everyone. I'm currently working on a project and my main objective is to get some addresses from a csv file, calculate the percentage of similarity that those addresses have with a trusted database and return that value. 
I have a code that is working however, when i try to calculate the similar rate,  i get an error with the "write to csv" function. The code only runs one line and then it crashes. The error starts occurring after line 30. Thanks in advance for your help and have a nice day.

Full code: https://pastebin.com/4sJZJtY9

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2393, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5239)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5085)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1207, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20405)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1215, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20359)
KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Teste.py", line 74, in <module>
    cp4[1].to_csv('AI.csv')
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2062, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2069, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1534, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3590, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2395, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5239)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5085)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1207, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20405)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1215, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20359)
KeyError: 1
```

Comment: line 29 is a comment......I don't think the error is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the error happens before the `to_csv` method call: `cp4` doesn't have the key `1`.

Have you read the traceback? It clearly states that the problem is in line 74:

```
File ".\Teste.py", line 74, in <module>
    cp4[1].to_csv('AI.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access `cp4[1]` and it looks like cp4 is dictionary like object and has no key `1`. Anyway it is little weird. While you iterate on `cp4` you're trying access to `cp4[1]`. Please think about it yet.